# How to Make 2 UIScrollViews show the same UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I don't know if that's possible, but I'm trying to make an app where I have 2 UIScrollViews in the same window and I want them to show the same UIView.

The purpose of that is having two UIScrollViews that show the same image in different zooms and pans...

Is that possible? If so, how? Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

A UIView can be a subview only of ONE view, so basically you cant have the same instance of the view be in both scrollviews, but you can have 2 instances of the UIView and put  one in each scroll view... So you new up two instance of the UIView, thats what you need to do...

```
   MyView *view1=[[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    MyView *view2=[[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    //then add each to its scrollview
```